# how to extract pairs of indexes randomly from matrix?

Tags: python

I'm having trouble implementing this, here I have a binary numpy array `A` which shape is (n, n).

I want to extract `t` pairs of indexes of element if it is 1. then store it in a list. No duplication (taking the index of same element ) is allowed.

For example, given `A = np.array([[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]])`, `t=2`,
an example of the expected output is

```
[(2, 1), (3, 2)]
```

can someone help me ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With list comprehension, you can do something like...

```
import numpy as np
import random

A = np.array([[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]])
t = 2
```

Get indices where value == 1/True

```
A_idx = [index for index, x in np.ndenumerate(A) if x]

print(A_idx)
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
```

Then extract random sample of size t from A_idx

```
A_rnd = [A_idx[i] for i in random.sample(range(len(A_idx)), t)]

print(A_rnd)
[(1, 0), (1, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like,

```
import numpy as np

t = 2 # the number of indexes to extract

# a 3x3 unit matrix, as an example
I = np.eye(3)

# Choose a linear index, no replacment
idx = np.random.choice(I.size, size = t, replace = False)

# print the unraveled index
print(np.unravel_index(idx, np.shape(I)))
```

The result will be, e.g.:

```
>> (array([0, 0]), array([0, 1]))
```